# ProjError: Error creating Transformer from CRS.:

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, geopandas, pyproj, fiona

I am having an issue with Geopandas and PyProj. 
I am loading a premade shp file from GeoPandas 
`borough = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))` 
When trying to do a crs transformation with the following code: 
`borough = borough.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})`  
I get the error:

> ProjError: Error creating Transformer from CRS.: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create_operations: SQLite error on SELECT source_crs_auth_name, source_crs_code, target_crs_auth_name, target_crs_code, cov.auth_name, cov.code, cov.table_name, area.south_lat, area.west_lon, area.north_lat, area.east_lon, ss.replacement_auth_name, ss.replacement_code FROM coordinate_operation_view cov JOIN area ON cov.area_of_use_auth_name = area.auth_name AND cov.area_of_use_code = area.code LEFT JOIN supersession ss ON ss.superseded_table_name = cov.table_name AND ss.superseded_auth_name = cov.auth_name AND ss.superseded_code = cov.code AND ss.superseded_table_name = ss.replacement_table_name AND ss.same_source_target_crs = 1 WHERE ((source_crs_auth_name = ? AND source_crs_code = ? AND target_crs_auth_name = ? AND target_crs_code = ?) OR (source_crs_auth_name = ? AND source_crs_code = ? AND target_crs_auth_name = ? AND target_crs_code = ?)) AND cov.deprecated = 0 AND cov.auth_name = ? ORDER BY pseudo_area_from_swne(south_lat, west_lon, north_lat, east_lon) DESC, (CASE WHEN accuracy is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), accuracy: no such column: ss.same_source_target_crs)

I really am totally clueless about what to do here. 

PS: This is my first stackoverflow post, so I apologize in advanced for the poor layout of this post.

Comment: How did you install geopandas and pyproj?

Comment: @martinfleis pipwin

Comment: I guess that your pyproj is not correctly installed. Any chance you can use `conda` to install it?

Comment: That fixed it for me, thank you!